# Reading registry of type list, when number of sub keys are unknown

Tags: batch-file, registrykey

I am trying to read the below regisry. It is of list type, whose number of sub-keys are not known.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Company\Domain\Config\Global\MACHINES_LIST\l1\C1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Company\Domain\Config\Global\MACHINES_LIST\l1\C2
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Company\Domain\Config\Global\MACHINES_LIST\l1\C3
```

.... so on. some entries less than 20
C1 contains V1=132.198.122.1
C2 contains V1=132.198.122.2
....

Below is the code I was trying for so long, but with no help.

```js
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Company\Domain\Config\Global\MACHINES_LIST\l1
set VALUE_NAME=V1

set /a loopChk=1
set /a count=1

:LOOPSATCON
 IF !loopChk! EQU 0 GOTO MOVE_OUT
 FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME%\C!count! /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul') DO (
   set IP=%%C
   set /a count=count+1
  )
 if defined ValueName (
  @echo IP= %IP%
 ) else (
  @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
  set /a loopChk=0
 )
 GOTO LOOPSATCON
```

---

Supplemental information transferred from "Answer"

Somehow i have managed to store get value of V1 from all the C1, C2, C3... sub keys. I have storing them in "ValueName" and immediately printing it. But still print is not happenning. This is first script. Thanks for your help.
Have I again done something wrong. 
This statement is executing "set ValueName=172.16.121.73", but still the value is not stored.

```dos
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Compnay\Domain\Config\Modality\Global\MACHINES_IP\l1

    FOR /F "skip=1" %%a IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% 2^>nul') DO (
        for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('REG QUERY "%%a" ^| Find "V1"') do (
            set ValueName=%%b
            @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
        )
        if defined ValueName (
                @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
            )
    )
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question? Two errors that are immediately obvious are that you are using `!loopchk!` without having invoked `enabledelayedexpansion` so "!loopchk!" will never equal "0" (the `!`s should be `%`) - the same goes for `!count!` (in which case you would need `enabledelayedexpansion` other wise that's just a string, not the value of `count`. You've used `if defined ValueName` which will always be false because you are setting `Value_Name` not `ValueName` and you don't appear to be assigning a value to it anywhere in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i have managed to store get value of V1 from all the C1, C2, C3... sub keys. I have storing them in "ValueName" and immediately printing it. But still print is not happenning. This is first script. Thanks for your help.
Have I again done something wrong. 
This statement is executing "set ValueName=172.16.121.73", but still the value is not stored.

```js
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Compnay\Domain\Config\Modality\Global\MACHINES_IP\l1
 
 FOR /F "skip=1" %%a IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% 2^>nul') DO (
  for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('REG QUERY "%%a" ^| Find "V1"') do (
   set ValueName=%%b
   @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
  )
  if defined ValueName (
          @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
         )
 )
```

Comment: To add additional information, you should `edit` your question. "Answers" are strictly for solutions to the problem. To avoid losing reputation, you should delete this response - I've edited it into your original question for you. Also - cut-and-paste, don't retype as it adds extra problems due to typos. Censor out sensitive information by say replacing your real password with `mypassword` as necessary. It's obvious that you've retyped this because your original posting showed `\Company\` but this shows `\Compnay\`.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier if we had the entire revised-code, but this is a standard`delayedexpansion`  problem

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note also the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

So - solution 1

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS enabledelayedexpansion
```

...

```
@echo Value Name = !ValueName!
```

Note that `!var!` is used in place of `%var%` to display the updated value in delayed-expansion mode.

Solution 2 (quick-and-easy version for `echo`ing values)

```
CALL echo Value Name = %%ValueName%%
```

Note that if you have executed `@echo off` then the `@` before a command is not necessary.

Comment: Hi Magoo & StackOverflow, Thanks for the help.
!ValueName! worked for me. I have created the batch file for appending the list of IP's. :)